# How can i slide these views from right to left on button clicked?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, animation, drawerlayout

I want to slide some views when and want it on tabbing this left arrow button.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbuMX.png

And after pressing this button I want to show views slides from the end of the screen to the left direction.

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBGoa.png

I found the SliderDrawer but that was deprecated years ago...
So any idea how can I achieve this.
For reference, you can look MxPlayer sliding menu that's what I actually want.

Comment: Sounds like a job for ViewPager or [navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui?gclid=Cj0KCQjw5oiMBhDtARIsAJi0qk3q-9Wnqqb1X39RfdiiMW8Bfm-noSg3RJ8Gl43UEjfpvGgNyxr_200aApV_EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#add_a_navigation_drawer), maybe.

Comment: an easy way to achieve this is create a container view group gone to the right of the arrow and adding the views programatically.  When you add the first button, then the container is visible, use a handler delay for example 500ms and an animation alpha 0 to 1 to show the new button.  Repeat 3 times, one for each button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have also thought to use it but from a memory point of view, I want a more robust solution. as navigation drawer is not made for this purpose although [SlidingDrawer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer) can work but its deprecated years ago.

Comment: @ManuelMato your approach is also good but it will take some memory and redraw the view..by the way, my below approach is the same but instead of adding menu buttons programmatically I just used translation property in XML and moved those views out of the screen and upon button clicked I just set translation property to 0f with 500ms delay for nice effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to use the navigation drawer layout but as of a little bit of performance enhancement, I was also thinking it will put some load if we looked at it from a device memory usage point of view.
I have achieved the same effect using a **translationX** property in XML and **animate()** function. A combination of these gave the same result which I was looking for.

**In XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:translationX="@dimen/_138sdp"
    tools:translationX="0dp">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/btn_action_menu"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:background="@drawable/shape_action_menu_bg"
       android:contentDescription="@null"
       android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />
    ........
</LinearLayout>
```

**On Jave/Kotlin side**

```
var rotation = 180f // For Arrow rotation effect from < to >
val translationX = binding.root.translationX
```

and for drawer-like effect, I've set click listener on the left arrow button and executed code like this.

```
binding.btnActionMenu.setOnClickListener {
    // This animation is for rotating arrow from < to > upon clicked
    it.animate().rotation(rotation).start()

    // This will drag or you can say open a menu from right to left with
    // 500ms delay effect.
    binding.actionMenuLayout.animate().also {
           .translationX(if(rotation != 0f) 0f else translationX)
           .duration = 500L
         }
         .animate.start()

    rotation = if(rotation == 0f) 180f else 0f
}
```

That's it.
Saves me from using the navigation drawer layout and a little bit of memory saving as well.

Menu Hides initially by setting **translationX** in xml:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbuMX.png 
Menu Shown upon arrow click from dragging it right to left with 500ms delay:-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBGoa.png